# why finite codimension is necessary here?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X = N \oplus Y$ be the direct sum of two linear subspace

Prove if codimension of $N$ is finite we have $\dim Y = \text{codim} N$

If we apply first isomorphism theorem to projection $P:X \to Y$ then easy to prove it,I was just not sure why finite codimension is necessary here.

Comment: It is true in generality, but you have to give a meaning to "dim" for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you,For infinite dimension space just gives the cardinality of basis.I was doing an exercise and the statement says for finite codimension,so I was not sure whether I made a false proof.